# No component factory found for undefined. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing a jasmine test for my angular 8 application that tests if an onOverlayClicked method is called on the click event. While running the test, I get the error

```
Error: No component factory found for undefined. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
        error properties: Object({ ngComponent: undefined, ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 37928961, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 4374528, directChildFlags: 4374528, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 1, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: 
Object({ ns: '', name: 'app-dialog', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent: <circular reference: Object>, renderParent: <circular reference: Object>, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 1, flags: 4374528, childFlags: 0, directChildFlags: 0, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object, matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object, ngContentIndex: 
-1, childCount: 0, bindings: Array, b ...
```

If I add the InsertionDirective to the entryComponents, I get error

```
Cannot add directive to entryComponents.
```

I am not sure what the problem is

Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DialogComponent } from '../../components/dialog/dialog.component';
import { InsertionDirective } from '../../shared/directives/insertion.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [DialogComponent, InsertionDirective],
  entryComponents: [DialogComponent]
})

export class DialogModule {}
```

Component

```
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, OnDestroy, Type, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { InsertionDirective } from '../../shared/directives/insertion.directive';
import { DialogRef } from './config/dialog-ref';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html'
})

export class DialogComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private readonly _onClose = new Subject<any>();

  public componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;
  public childComponentType: Type<any>;
  public onClose = this._onClose.asObservable();

  // add this:
  @ViewChild(InsertionDirective, { static: false })
  insertionPoint: InsertionDirective;

  constructor(public componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              public cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
              public dialog: DialogRef) {
    console.log('My InsertionPoint');
    console.log(this.insertionPoint);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadChildComponent(this.childComponentType);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.componentRef) {
      this.componentRef.destroy();
    }
  }

  onOverlayClicked(evt: MouseEvent) {
    // close the dialog
  }

  onDialogClicked(evt: MouseEvent) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }

  loadChildComponent(componentType: Type<any>) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);

    const viewContainerRef = this.insertionPoint.viewContainerRef;
    console.log(viewContainerRef);
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.dialog.close();
  }
}
```

Test component

```
describe('DialogComponent', () => {
  let component: DialogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DialogComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SharedModule, DialogModule], // DialogModule
      //  declarations: [ InsertionDirective ],
      providers: [ DialogRef ]
    })
    .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [DialogComponent] } })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DialogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should set call onOverlayClicked click', () => {
   // const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    spyOn(component, 'onOverlayClicked');
    const overlay = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.overlay'));
    overlay.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.onOverlayClicked).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
});
```

InsertionDirective

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInsertion]',
})
export class InsertionDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, could it be the way you are importing the directive into the dialog component and using viewchild as well? Have you tried to remove these references and see if you can get further with the test since all you do is log this to the console?

Comment: nope if you see in the loadChildComponent method , I am using it for getting the viewContainerRef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your DialogComponent class, you are programatically creating an Angular component using ComponentResolver as shown in the snippet below:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.loadChildComponent(this.childComponentType);
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}

loadChildComponent(componentType: Type<any>) {
  const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);

  const viewContainerRef = this.insertionPoint.viewContainerRef;
  console.log(viewContainerRef);
  viewContainerRef.clear();

  this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
}
```

The value of the object`childComponentType`, for which you are creating a component programatically, is never initialized in your Unit test and hence it is throwing the error `No component factory found for undefined`.

Let's say you want to programatically create an instance for XYZComponent, you have to set it in the Unit test as below:

```
describe('DialogComponent', () => {
  let component: DialogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DialogComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SharedModule, DialogModule], // DialogModule
      //  declarations: [ InsertionDirective ],
      /*
      * Since you want to programatically create an instance of XYZComponent
      * DialogComponent, include XYZComponent in entryComponents array
      */
      entryComponents: [XYZComponent],
      providers: [ DialogRef ]
    })
    .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [DialogComponent] } })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DialogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // initialize childComponentType object
    component.childComponentType = XYZComponent;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should set call onOverlayClicked click', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'onOverlayClicked');
    const overlay = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.overlay'));
    overlay.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.onOverlayClicked).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

This should resolve your errors now. Note that you have to include XYZComponent in entryComponents array for Angular to resolve the component at runtime.

Comment: In my case its Dialog component that is the entry point. It is already added in the overridemodule declaration in the beforeeach. I assigned Dialog Component in they second beforeEach as you have shown but still getting the same error

Comment: I am bit confused. If i try to add xyz component that is currently part of my appmodule, i get error saying it is not part of ngmodule.  Also like you mentioned, it doesn't allow me to add entryComponents: [XYZComponent] in the place as you have shown. I have added it to the overridemodule declaration. Removed dialog component and replaced it with xyzcomponent. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: It finally worked for me. I had do a few tweaks. Thanks a lot